# appending extra data to a file -python

Tags: python

I having hard time trying to append extra data to a file.
duplicate index number 2 times and add 22, and 23, leaving the phone number
on the existing line 20.
example

original

myfile:

```
1,20,323.454.1234,
2,20,212.333.3333,
3,20,212.222.4444,
4,20,850.234.3881,
5,20,850.111.3881,
6,20,510-222-5241,
7,20,510-343-5241,
8,20,678-456-3555,
9,20,678-123-3555,
10,20,123-123-4878,
```

the new file suppose to be like this
mynewfile:

```
1,20,323.454.1234,
1,22,323.454.1234,
1,23,323.454.1234,
2,20,212.333.3333,
2,22,212.333.3333,
2,23,212.333.3333,
3,20,212.222.4444,
3,22,212.222.4444,
3,23,212.222.4444,
4,20,850.234.3881,
4,22,850.234.3881,
4,23,850.234.3881,
5,20,850.111.3881,
5,22,850.111.3881,
5,23,850.111.3881,
6,20,510-222-5241,
6,22,510-222-5241,
6,23,510-222-5241,
7,20,510-343-5241,
7,22,510-343-5241,
7,23,510-343-5241,
8,20,678-456-3555,
8,22,678-456-3555,
8,23,678-456-3555,
9,20,678-123-3555,
9,22,678-123-3555,
9,23,678-123-3555,
10,20,123-123-4878,
10,22,123-123-4878,
10,20,123-123-4878,
```

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re

myfile = open('myfile', 'r+')
lines = myfile.readlines()
sentences = []
for line in lines:
         if line:
           sentences.insert(line + '22')
     for line in lines:
         if line:
            sentences.insert(line + '23')
myfile.close()



outputfile = open('mynewfile', 'w+')
if len(sentences) > 0:
   for sentence in sentences:
       outputfile.write(sentence)

outputfile.close()
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, what does your existing code do wrong? If you can explain that, it will help to solve it. (I mean besides failing to even compile with an `IndentationError`, and one that makes it hard to guess what you actually meant…)

Answer (score 2):

Just some hints, so you can come up to the solution yourself.
You can just read the input file line by line.  Use something like:

```
with open("myfile", "rt") as f, open ("mynewfile", "wt") as g:
  for line in f:
    # split line and generate your two new lines
    print >> g, line
    print >> g, ... # new line 1
    print >> g, ... # new line 2
```

You'll need to split each line in pieces, use `split` for that.

Comment: Or, if they are on python 3.x, they would use `print(line, file=g)`.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
import fileinput

with fileinput.input() as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line, end='')
        fields = line.split(r',', 2)
        for n in [22, 23]:
            fields[1] = n 
            print(','.join(map(str, fields)), end='')
```

It yields:

```
1,20,323.454.1234,
1,22,323.454.1234,
1,23,323.454.1234,
2,20,212.333.3333,
2,22,212.333.3333,
2,23,212.333.3333,
3,20,212.222.4444,
3,22,212.222.4444,
3,23,212.222.4444,
4,20,850.234.3881,
4,22,850.234.3881,
4,23,850.234.3881,
5,20,850.111.3881,
5,22,850.111.3881,
5,23,850.111.3881,
6,20,510-222-5241,
6,22,510-222-5241,
6,23,510-222-5241,
7,20,510-343-5241,
7,22,510-343-5241,
7,23,510-343-5241,
8,20,678-456-3555,
8,22,678-456-3555,
8,23,678-456-3555,
9,20,678-123-3555,
9,22,678-123-3555,
9,23,678-123-3555,
10,20,123-123-4878,
10,22,123-123-4878,
10,23,123-123-4878,
```

Comment: thanks... man. I know is too much asking but i forgot to said that lines with the 22, 23 don't need phone number... how would i make that changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in open('myfile.txt'):
    x = x.rstrip()
    L = x.split(',')
    print(x)
    print(L[0], 22, L[2], "\n", sep=',', end='')
    print(L[0], 23, L[2], "\n", sep=',', end='')
```

Comment: sorry... I just tried. I give up... 

version 2.6.6 
gives error.  

File "fix_hb_master.py", line 7
    print(line, end='')
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

version: 3.0

File "fix_hb_master.py", line 5, in <module>
    with fileinput.input() as f:
AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute '__exit__'

any ideas?

Comment: once i found the right version everything work fine. I just changed the L[2] to [3] to empty 22,23 fields.